# How to test only one of multiple method calls in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
def some_method
  subject.put(1)
  subject.put(2)
  ...
end
```

the below fails as there were more than one call to `put`, is it possible to only validate that the first call occurred not care about the rest?

```
expect(subject).to receive(:put).with(1).once
```

Answer (score 1):

Played around a bit and the following worked.

```
allow(subject).to receive(:put)
expect(subject).to receive(:put).with(1).once
```

Answer (score 0):

typically you'd seperate the setup and the expectations like this:

```
before do
  allow(subject).to receive(:put)
end

it 'invokes put' do
  expect(subject).to receive(:put).with(1).once
end
```